# AlertIOS undefined errors (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to use [AlertIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alertios.html) in a brand new React Native project, but for some reason I'm getting `undefined`-related errors.

The relevant parts of the code:

```
import { AlertIOS } from 'react-native';

// Callback for a button press
const _alert = () => {
  AlertIOS.alert('title', 'text')
}
```

If I'm not in debug mode, after clicking the button I get the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.AlertIOS.alert')`.

When debugging, the error changes to `Cannot read property alert of undefined` and AlertIOS has the value shown in the print below, which doesn't seem right.

Also, if I just use `Alert.alert`, it works (obviously changing the import).

[image]

Comment: Are you checking in Ios Device/Simulator because it will not work in Android. According to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alertios#alert) ,  We recommend using the Alert.alert method for cross-platform support if you don't need to create iOS-only prompts.

Comment: @MehranKhan I was testing in the iOS Simulator, but AlertIOS was removed (check the accepted answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem in RN 0.60. Seem like it's removed. You can check its source https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js#L50

There are some good alternatives like [this one](https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-prompt)

Comment: Yeah, I just found the commit that removed it, weird that the official documentation isn't updated.

Answer (score 2):

In RN 0.61, the AlertIOS functionality is now part of Alert itself. So for example, instead of AlertIOS.prompt, you can do the following:

```
import {Alert} from 'react-native';

Alert.prompt('Alert Title', 'message', [
    {
        text: 'ok',
        onPress: str => console.log('Entered string: ' + str),
    },
    {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Pressed Cancel!'),
        style: 'cancel',
    },
]);
```

See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25744) issue for details